# D3 cannot append to SVG from within function

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am attempting to append some shapes on to an SVG block from within a function call using the following code...

```
function generateNodes(){
    var data = [[0,0],[100,100]];
    d3.select("svg").selectAll("circle")
        .data(data)
      .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class","test")
        .attr("r", 5)
        .attr("cx", function(d){ return d[0]; })
        .attr("cy", function(d){ return d[1]; });
}
```

However nothing is appearing in the SVG after I call generateNodes() in the console. When I try..

`d3.selectAll(".test")`

it returns an array of length 0 implying nothing has been inserted into the DOM.

This leads me to presume that this is an issue with either the .enter() or .data() functions not being used correctly.

I tried coding up an example in JSfiddle which seems to be working, which makes the above code even more confusing. http://jsfiddle.net/LLbf3x0c/

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: Please post your edit as a separate answer.

Comment: Most likely you already have `circle` elements on your page when it isn't working and hence the enter selection is empty. See section 5 of [this tutorial](https://www.airpair.com/d3.js/getting-started-tutorial) for more background info.

Comment: Exactly right, thanks for the info. Your tutorial sums it up perfectly "Most of the problems new users of D3 encounter are because of a lack of understanding of the implications of D3's data-driven approach and the selections. "